# Define GNU Assembler (GAS) macro that expands to it self non recursively

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

I want to build rvv 1.0 code with rvv 0.7.1. Between the versions vsetvli got extra flag arguments which can be ignored for rvv 0.7.1.
My current approach to make existing rvv 1.0 code working without modifying it is the following:

```
.macro vsetvli0p7 rd, rs1, e=e8, m=m1, T=1, M=1
    .ifc \m, mf2
    NOT SUPPORTED IN rvv0.7
    .endif
    .ifc \m, mf4
    NOT SUPPORTED IN rvv0.7
    .endif
    .ifc \m, mf8
    NOT SUPPORTED IN rvv0.7
    .endif
    vsetvli \rd, \rs1, \e, \m
.endm
#define vsetvli vsetvli0p7
```

This works when you compile with the c preprocessor enabled.
My problem is now, that code from a submodule, which I can't modify easily, has comments with `# if something ...` and `# assert valid input`. This causes an error when the c preprocessor is enabled.

My only solution seems to be to disable the c preprocessor when compiling this file, this is easily done by changing my file which incorporates the code:

```
...
.endm
-#include "submodule/file.s"
+.include "submodule/file.s"
```

This works because the c preprocessor is executed before GAS macros are expanded.

Now back to my question, how do I replace the `#define vsetvli vsetvli0p7` with a GAS macro/directive, without causing infinite recursion?

I know that I could just modify my build system and e.g. make a temporary copy of `"submodule/file.s"` and strip the offending comments, but that makes redistribution harder in my case, so I'd like to know if it's possible to write such a macro in GAS.